# How set edge color with an different object in cytoscape js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I have an object like this:

edge

```
...,{\"data\":{\"label\":\"test\",\"source\":\"1\",\"target\":\"19\",\"extra\": 
{\"color\":\"#000000\",\"width\":\"#000000\"}}},{\"data\":
{\"label\":\"1~20\",\"source\":\"1\",\"target\":\"20\",\"extra\":
{\"color\":\"#FF0000\",\"width\":\"5\"}}},...
```

I am able to parse it, read it and display my nodes and edges into `cytoscape.js`, but I cannot figure out how to access the extra components to set color and width.

Here:

```cs
.selector("edge")
                    .css({
                        "width": "mapData(weight, 0, 100, 1, 4)",
                        "target-arrow-shape": "triangle",
                        "source-arrow-shape": "circle",
                        "line-color": "data.extra(color)"//data(color)
                    })
```

I know how to acess the color property if it's outside extra, but I would like to use it inside the extra component, as one can see in the **JSON** example.

Please, how should I access my extra components to set the css color?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This document was more helpful to me than the accepted answer: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/master/documentation/md/style.md#function-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you build from the trunk, I've pushed a fix to allow `data(extra.color)` style syntax in mappers.